# PyQt SQL Many to Many relationship

Tags: sql, sqlite, pyqt4, pyqt5

Is it possible to have joins in an sqlrelationaltablemodel? How do you do joins and show the data? I suspect that this is not possible, but wanted to check. I am using a sqlrelationaltablemodel. How can you do joins and add that to the model?

In pure sql I can do this:

```
    SELECT * FROM rt_table_has_mgmt_desc
INNER JOIN rt_table on rt_table_has_mgmt_desc.rt_table_id = rt_table.id
INNER JOIN mgmt_desc ON mgmt_desc.id = rt_table_has_mgmt_desc.mgmt_desc_id
INNER JOIN mgmt_desc_lu ON mgmt_desc_lu.id = mgmt_desc.mgmt_lu_id;
```

How do I do this in a model in PyQt? I suspect you can't, but what is the work around here?
What I want is this:

2 1 77 blm 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 Limited

3 1 78 blm 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 Closed

4 1 79 blm 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 Open

5 1 80 blm 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 Limited

6 6 81 blm 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 Open

7 10 82 blm 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 Limited

8 11 83 blm 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 Closed

my db schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE rt_table_has_mgmt_desc (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    rt_table_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    mgmt_desc_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_rt_table_has_mgmt_desc_rt_table1' FOREIGN KEY ( rt_table_id ) REFERENCES rt_table ( id ) ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_rt_table_has_mgmt_desc_mgmt_desc1' FOREIGN KEY ( mgmt_desc_id ) REFERENCES mgmt_desc ( id )
    );



 CREATE TABLE mgmt_desc (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    entry_date TEXT NOT NULL,
    start_date TEXT NOT NULL,
    End_date TEXT,
    mgmt_lu_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_mgmt_lu_mgmt_lu_id' FOREIGN KEY ( mgmt_lu_id ) REFERENCES mgmt_desc_lu ( id ) ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    );



 CREATE TABLE mgmt_desc_lu (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    mgmt_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    mgmt_alias TEXT NOT NULL,
    mgmt_def TEXT NOT NULL
    );
```